# Developing multiple stateless logic apps in VSCode

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm creating multiple stateless logic apps. My folder structure is as follows:

```
Fun1\
\-- workflow.json
Fun2\
\-- workflow.json
parameters.json
```

What I don't quite understand is why when creating a parameter in a workflow, then it gets added to `parameters.json` instead of that workflow's `"parameters":{}`? Because of this fact, I can see that parameter in any workflow which is a bit odd. Moreover, it complicates the things when thinking about deploying...

From what I observe, this is sort of structure is not really fit for stateless logic apps, but it's more suited to a standard logic app that can host multiple workflows. Am I wrong with this assumption?

How should I handle my case?

Comment: Could you please give us some clarity whether you are creating the workflow using visual studio or visual studio code both follows different file structure. 
- if you are creating  a logic app and workflow using visual studio code here is the [file structure](https://i.imgur.com/AUYrK1O.png)
- if you are creating the logic app using visual studio then your  project will have logicapp.json & logicapp.parameters.json file as shown in [this](https://i.imgur.com/kwZj3nc.png) image.

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MT I'm creating the workflows in VS Code, by using the Logic App extensions. I have the same file structure as the one you've shown.

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MT any opinion on this matter related to the parameters handling?

Answer (score 0):

Currently,If you use either portal or visual studio code to built your standard logic app,you can define parameters using the parameters.json file & you can reference any parameter in these parameters file from any workflow in your project's workflow.json file or from any connection object in your project's connections.json file.

For more information you refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/parameterize-workflow-app?tabs=azure-portal#visual-studio-code) documentation , about usage of parameter in single-tenant or standard logic app.